# Method parameter copied (not moved)

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I have the following code:

```
// header
    void Method1(const bool& b, std::vector<int>&& v);
    bool Method2();

bool CMyClass::Method1()
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 1, 2, 3 };
    TRACE("%d\n", v.size());
    Method2(true, std::move(v));
    TRACE("%d\n", v.size());
    return true;
}

void CMyClass::Method2(const bool& b, std::vector<int>&& v)
{
    TRACE("%d\n", v.size());
}
```

Outcome:

3

3

3

Seems `v` is copied, if so, why not moved?

Comment: It's neither copied nor moved. `Method2` takes a reference, that refers back to `v` local variable in `Method1`. Print `&v`, see for yourself. `std::move` doesn't itself move anything, it just gives a permission to move from its argument. Something must then act on this permission for the move to actually occur; in your example, nothing does.

Comment: "Something must then act on this permission for the move" What should be done to actually move `v`?

Comment: At the very least, there should be another object of type `std::vector<int>` that `v` could be moved **to**. E.g. `Method2` could have `std::vector<int> v2 = std::move(v);`

Comment: The other aspect is that a moved-from object is in a "valid but undefined" state. Undefined means that you have no guarantees whatsoever! In `Method1` you seem to expect that `v.size` is different after the `std::move`-line. But `v` is undefined, its size can have any value - including `3`.